# Changing IFrame src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with a few test pages and I'm having trouble loading the pages in to the IFrame with the src attribute using jQuery. All the pages are local.

Here are the scripts I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $("#iframeBox").attr("src", "Default.aspx");
    });
});
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $("#iframeBox").attr("src") = "Defualt.aspx";
    });
});
```

This is the markup for the IFrame:

```
<iframe id="iframeBox" src="Copy of Default.aspx"></iframe>
```

I tried to use this code with online pages and it still didn't work.

If using IFrames is a bad idea, could you please recommend me a different method I can use.
The idea of the site is to show a lot of galleries with subjects that the user can browse
and every page should hold a gallery.

I'm using the: `galleriffic` jQuery plugin.

Comment: for some reson the ifram markup is not showing in the question here it is:      <iframe id="iframeBox" src="Copy of Default.aspx"></iframe>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the attribute won't change the location of the iframe.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframeBox" name="iframeBox" src="watever"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.iframeBox.location.href = "Defualt.aspx";
```

But I recommend to use div's for that:

HTML:

```
<div id="iframeBox" data-src="watever.aspx"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("div#iframeBox").css("overflow", "auto"); // or do it in css
 $.get($("div#iframeBox").data("src")).success(function(data) {
     $("div#iframeBox").html(data);
 }).error(function() { $("div#iframeBox").html("Could not load page."); });
```

You can change the page like this:

```
 $.get("Default.aspx").success(function(data) {
     $("div#iframeBox").html(data);
 }).error(function() { alert("Error while changing page!"); });
```

Comment: btw what is data-src attribute? i never seen that befor

Comment: @samy actually I've just added the div version. You can add any data-watever attribute w3c allowed. But if you don't want you can change it in the script.